# Anticommutator BRST charge and $c$-ghost mode

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, conventions, brst, ghosts

My goal is to compute the anticommutator $\{Q_B, c_m\}$ where $Q_B$ is the BRST charge in string theory and $c_m$ is the $m$th mode of the $c$ ghost field
$$
c(z) = \sum_m \frac{c_m}{z^{m-1}}
$$
(since the weight of $c$ is $-1$). The problem is that I computed the result in two different ways and they do not agree. Moreover none of them agree with the results I have found in two books (which themselves seem to not agree).

## First method

I get the first expression by starting with
$$
\{Q_B, c(z)\} = c(z) \partial c(z)
$$
(until here everyone agrees). Then I expand both sides in series and I obtain (after shifting $m \to m-n$ to identify the $z^{m-1}$ factors on both sides)
$$
\{Q_B, c_m\} = - \sum_n (n - 1) c_{m-n} c_n
= - \sum_n (m + n - 1) c_{-n} c_{m+n}.
$$

## Second method

Now the second way is by using the commutator with a primary operator $\phi$ of dimension $h$
$$
[Q_B, \phi_m] = \sum_n \big( n (h-1) - m\big) c_{m-n} \phi_n.
$$
I computed this expression from (found in books)
$$
[Q_B, \phi(z)] = h\, \partial c(z)\, \phi(z) + c(z) \partial \phi(z)
$$
and it agrees with the literature for $h = 1$ (I did not find it anywhere for $h \neq 1$). Since $c$ is a primary operator I should be able to use this formula which gives
$$
[Q_B, c_m] = - \sum_n (2 n + m) c_{m-n} c_n.
$$
One puzzle in this formula is that the RHS of $[Q_B, \phi(z)]$ for $\phi = c$ is
$$
- \partial c(z)\, c(z) + c(z) \partial c(z)
= 2 c(z) \partial c(z)
$$
using the fact that $c$ anticommutes. There is an additional factor $2$.

## Literature

Note : I have changed some indices in order to bring everyone with the closest possible form.

The book of Blumenhagen, Lüst and Theisen (Basic Concepts of String Theory, p. 114 eq. (5.38)) gives
$$
[Q_B, c_m] = - \sum_n (2 m + n) c_{-n} c_{m+n}.  \tag{5.38}
$$
Similarly the book from Lawrie (A Unified Grand Tour of Theoretical Physics, p. 540, eq. (15.176)) gives
$$
[Q_B, c_m] = - \frac{1}{2} \sum_n (2 n + m) c_{-n} c_{m+n}. \tag{15.176}
$$
Both expressions differ in the parenthesis factor. Compared with my second method this almost agree, except for the indices of the $c$.